# How to find the button element through Selenium webdriver and xpath

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriver

[snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0JunD.jpg)

```
 <button class="add-school btnEditDashboard btn btn-primary pull-right" ng-click="CreateNewSchool()" name="AddSchool" type="submit">Add School</button>
```

Tried xpath also. (`\\html/body/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/button`)

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"tag name","selector":"AddSchool"}
```

Comment: What is your actual question? What does the HTML code you are trying the Xpath on, look like?

Comment: I guess, you  are trying to find the element using tag name with the value addschool. You have to use the right method.

Comment: Please check whether it's in iframe or not ?

Comment: fine sir it working with iframe focus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with this code :

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//button[text()='Add School' and @name='AddSchool' and @ng-click='CreateNewSchool()']"))).click();
```

If it is in **iframe** , please switch focus of driver to respective **iframe** and then try to interact with it.

Answer (score 1):

`AddSchool` is the `name` attribute, not the `tag name` (which will be `button` in your case). Try

```
findElement(By.name("AddSchool"))
```

Comment: Tried bro not working  Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"class name","selector":"AddSchool"}

Comment: @NagaNaveenb You may need to add some wait before find the element.

Comment: @NagaNaveenb You need to use `By.name`, not `By.className`

Answer (score 1):

To locate the element instead of using an *absolute xpath* it would be optimum to use a *relative xpath*. Now, as per the *HTML* you have shared the element is an [**Angular**](https://angular.io/) element so you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the *element to be clickable* as follows:

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//button[@class='add-school btnEditDashboard btn btn-primary pull-right' and @name='AddSchool']"))).click();
```

Comment: I do not get this point "logical xpath" ? what is logical xpath ? Either it's a relative or absolute.

Answer (score 1):

Since the HTML is not shared, it could be 2 things

1. Iframe: You need to change your drivers focus to the iframe the element is in.
   https://www.guru99.com/handling-iframes-selenium.html
2. Selenium is executing before the element is visible. Use Explicit Wait to wait for the element to be interactable before clicking it. Understand all the type of wait conditions through http://www.seleniumeasy.com/selenium-tutorials/webdriver-wait-examples

Answer (score 0):

Try this xpath:

```
//button[@ng-click='CreateNewSchool()']
```

Comment: Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//button[@ng-click='CreateNewSchool()']"}

Comment: @NagaNaveenb Check with Debugger,  Are you at correct location to find element  . If so, you need to wait for a moment until page is being loaded. You can try with Explicit Wait or Thread.sleep();